# How to create a Unix shell script for checking duplicate rows in a files?

Tags: shell, unix

Please help me to create a Unix shell script for checking duplicate rows in a files?

Example file data contains

```
VTZ000000000,1248317832172
VTZ000000001,7604750485177
VTZ000000002,2594177482232
VTZ000000003,7604750485177
VTZ000000001,2594177482232
```

- Condition 1: check the duplicates in 1 column
- Condition 2: check the duplicates in 2 columns (if condition 1 is satisfied)
- Condition 3: sort the input file and save into `temp_file` if condition 2 is satisfied)
- Condition 4: check the difference

Comment: `Can you please help me?` Only if you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) first.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected results at least? The way I read your question, there is now duplicate row in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read `man uniq` for full details on how to solve this question